# Set default value of property of object passed on parameter to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The key difference on this question is I want to keep my property referenced inside the object, not destructured.

```
export interface MapSettings {
  up: 'trueNorth' | 'runIn' | 'magneticNorth' | 'user';
  rotation?: number;
}

type MapProps = {
  settings: MapSettings;
};

export const Map: FunctionComponent<MapProps> = function Map({
  settings,
}) {
```

I want to set a default value for `settings.rotation` but I also want to keep it referenced as `settings.rotation` because settings has a lot more properties than shown here and I know where the value is coming from.

This is the best answer I can come up with:

```
export const Map: FunctionComponent<MapProps> = function Map({
  settings: { rotation: settingsRotation = 360, ...settings },
}) {
```

But it doesn't let me reference `settings.rotation` with a default value of `360`.

Comment: just check the property in the first line of your function and set it if it isn't set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check it and set it:

```
export const Map: FunctionComponent<MapProps> = function Map({
  settings,
}) {
  settings.rotation = (settings.rotation || settings.roation === 0) ? settings.rotation : 360
```

Comment: I was just hoping there would be a way in the constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default value is mentioned as `{ someKey = 'defaultValue' }` insead of `{ someKey: 'defaultValue' }

So you can write it like

```
{
   settings = { rotation: settingsRotation = 360 },
}
```