# Typing property of a variable which possibly has empty-object type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

### Background

I'm using React and TypeScript and trying to add an optional parameter to a component. Then I run into a typescript error (ts:2339).

It seems that, when no props is passed, React will pass `props={}` instead of `props=null` or `props=undefined`. So the functional component will receive `{}`(an empty object), and I cannot change that.

### Problem

How should I let TypeScript read the real optional parameters with pre-defined values?

```js
const f = (param: {} | { k: string } = { k: 'v' }) => {
    var o
    // test 1 TS error: Property 'k' does not exist on type '{} | { k: string; }'.  Property 'k' does not exist on type '{}'.(2339)
    // o = (param)?.k 

    // test 2, nullity test. Same error as test1
    // if (Object.entries(param).length === 0) param = { k: 'v' };
    // o = (param)?.k

    // test 3, trying to avoid optional param assignment. Same error as test1
    // const _param = param ?? { k: 'v' }
    // o = _param.k

    // current work-around
    o = (param as any)?.k
    console.log(o)
}
f()
```

See the code in TS playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFABwIYCcMFsBcMA3gL4wA+xMA1odFgJZgDmMZyRNhA5AG7dsAlEgB8xAFAwpMXthghJ0gPRKYUAKbQYARhgAVAMox1WLCCyEACmbQmoATxjdqAgCYhNMMCFjqAHgxa4Gr2tk6kFFS0MPRMzADcbNwAdFLWILZYDk4uMO6e3r4BQWAhYdykKSgATADMtQCcgopSKvJIqJg4uIIA-MnUMOItMG0aWtUANF4ArgA2cwzZ41CpBnjqxqbmMBgQappQ2iNtDAgoAPIARgBW6sCr6mBQjJro2HiCyXNPzFAAFkhEMgAAzCLp4DqcaJ8AQkeInVQgDrvbp9AbDaSjVQrGC1aYvexxNTIjC8EAMVzyNBQBjgDBzGAQ3C7CAQBjMMC4J6rGDrblbMxYVkHaDHLFtUCQWAAfWZHXlvV6UR4-DYiPayDlH1wGI1wBmph5MAA7uZqABabAgGZgVwjZHIVGQva7MD2dHUEZSiAgH7fEDMFAgZokcRwFCCIA

The `param` variable is never empty in this example and always has the property `k`. Yet I cannot use `param?.k` or anything I can come up with. I know that the `any` type works like disabling the TypeScript function. So, is there a way to let TypeScript read the true value of the parameter? Thanks.

### What I did

I've read almost all similar questions on Stack Overflow but I see no good answer. Here are some references.

- test2: [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)
- test3: [Set default value of property of object passed on parameter to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123495/set-default-value-of-property-of-object-passed-on-parameter-to-function)
- I can't use `null` instead of `{}` because of React.
- I think this can be helpful but I can't find API on non-route component: [React route params with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678961/react-route-params-with-default-value) .
- This one is with the class component, but not resolving my question: [Default property value in React component using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282159/default-property-value-in-react-component-using-typescript)

Comment: how is this component used in your template? I am not sure what you mean by:  "It seems that react will pass props={} instead of props=null or props=undefined. So I the functional component need will receive {}(an empty object)"

Comment: I did not make it clear. I meant in the case of "when no props were passed". I edited the question as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directy [destructure the parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) in the function signature with a default value to always get the value:

```
const f = ({ k = 'v' }: { k?: string }) => {
  ...
```

and then do `var o = k`.

Alternatively you can test if `k` is a key of `param`. This can be done with:

```
if ('k' in param) {
  o = param.k
}
```

but it is more cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you, @daylily. The first code style is not resolving the problem I described, which is to pass the parameter type correctly. Also, we need to check each property manually. The second code is exactly what I wanted. I suggest moving it as the principal solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { FC } from 'react'

type Props = {
    k: string
}

const foo: FC<Props> = (props = { k: 'v' }) => {

    const { k } = props // string

    return null as any

}
```

Since you have provided default value for props, you can omit any checkings of `k`